# Looking for difference between re.match(pattern, ...) and re.search(r'\A' + pattern, ...)

Tags: python, regex

(All the code below assumes a context where `import re` has already been evaluated.)

The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) on the differences between `re.match` and `re.search` specifically compares running `re.match(pattern, ...)` with running `re.search('^' + pattern, ...)`.  This seems to me a bit of a strawman, because the real test would be to compare `re.match(pattern, ...)` with `re.search(r'\A' + pattern, ...)`<sup>1</sup>.

To be more specific, I for one can't readily come up with a combination of `pattern` and `string` for which the outcome of

```
m = re.match(pattern, string)
```

will differ from the outcome of

```
m = re.search(r'\A' + pattern, string)
```

(Note that if the original pattern in `pattern` happens to be of type `unicode`, so is the revised pattern in `r'\A' + pattern`, conveniently enough.)

Let me emphasize that here I'm *not* interested in possible differences in performance, convenience, etc.  At the moment I'm interested only in differences in the final outcomes (i.e. differences in the final values of `m`).

To phrase the question somewhat more generally, I'm looking for a combination of `pattern`, `flags`, `string`, and `kwargs` such that the final value of `m` in

```
r0 = re.compile(pattern, flags=flags)
m = r0.match(string, **kwargs)
```

differs from the final value of `m` in

```
r1 = re.compile(r'\A' + pattern, flags=flags)
m = r1.search(string, **kwargs)
```

It may be that no such combination of the inputs `pattern`, `flags`, `string`, and `kwargs` exists, but to be able to make this assertion with any confidence would require an in-depth knowledge of the internals of Python's regex engine.  IOW, in contrast to a "positive answer" (i.e. one consisting of just *one* combination of inputs as described), a "negative answer" to this question amounts to a rather authoritative statement, so for it to be convincing requires that the case be made at a much deeper level (than for a "positive" answer).

To sum up: I'm looking answers of one of two possible kinds:

1. A combination of `pattern`, `flags`, `string`, and `kwargs` that will produce different values of `m` in the last two cases given above;
2. An authoritative "negative" answer (i.e. no such combination of inputs exists), based on knowledge of the internals of Python regular expressions.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> `\A` anchors the matching to the beginning of the string, irrespective of whether the matching is multiline or not.  BTW, the counterpart of `\A` for end-of-string matching is `\Z`.  Annoyingly enough, Python's `\Z` corresponds to Perl's `\z`, and *not* to Perl's `\Z`.  This tripped me when I wrote an earlier version of this post.  (BTW, in Python regexes `\z` has no special meaning; it just matches `z`.)  Thanks to [John Y](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95852/john-y) for spotting my error.</sub>

Comment: Your mnemonic is wrong. According to the documentation you linked to, the counterpart to `\A` is `\Z`. Capitals in both cases. To be sure, I tested it in an interactive Python session and the behavior matched the docs. `\z` (lowercase) behaved the same as `z` (i.e. the backslash made no difference, which is normal for characters that do not have any special regex meaning in Python).

Comment: Thanks for spotting my error!  I've fixed it now.  I misremembered Perl's special regex sequences as if they were Python's.  What I really need is is a mnemonic for keeping those two straight!

Answer (score 0):

There might be something I am not seeing here, but I think the difference is clear.

1. `re.match()` returns a successful match **only if** the pattern you are looking for is at the start of the string, and from the look of the examples in the documentation it seems that `re.match()` uses `\A` to anchor the match to the start of the string and **not** the start-of-line in multi-line mode.
2. `re.search()` returns a successful match **no matter** where the pattern is inside the target string as long as there is a match, of course as long as you don't anchor the pattern intentionally.

Now answering your main question, about what is the difference between `re.match(pattern, …)` and `re.search(r'\A' + pattern, …)` ?

Well there is no difference whatsoever, it is just a convenience method just so you don't have to type `r'\A' + pattern` each time I guess if you want to anchor your match which happens a lot i suppose.

You can be more sure that `re.match()` uses `\A` internally just by looking at the last example in the comparison link you posted:

```
>>> re.match('X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # No match
>>> re.search('^X', 'A\nB\nX', re.MULTILINE)  # Match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at ...>
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question; I have added wording to my post (mostly at the end) in a way that hopefully will make such misunderstanding less likely.

Comment: @kjo I think I understand question number 1 of the two you have asked, I am not an authoritative source but I am certain you won't find a combination where the two match different things.

Comment: here's the thing: I could also say that "I'm certain" that I won't find such a combination," where by this what I *really* mean is that I just can't think of one, or even of how there *could* be one.  Therefore, the only point of posting a question like this one would be for me to either get some confirmation (from someone with more expert/behind-the-scenes knowledge than I have) of this "certainty", or get some refutation of this "certainty" (in the form of an example that shows that my "certainty" was actually unfounded--after all, regexes are a notoriously counterintuitive concept).

Comment: @kjo I see your point. I think if they have called the method `startsWith` it would be more convenience. Nevertheless I feel OK with it as I know what to expect from those two methods whenever I call them and without knowing how they work internally and this is fine by me.